# Key press in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used jQuery to event for key press. Here is my command:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind('keydown', 'f1', function() {
    alert('f1');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'f2', function() {
        alert('f2');
    });
});
```

I want when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> key I will get a `alert('f1')` and when I press >kbd>F2 key I will get a `alert('f2')`

But when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> key, I get 2 `alert('f1')`. 
How can I get a `alert('f1')` when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> key?

Comment: You want a single alert?

Comment: Hint: what does the jQuery documentation say the second parameter of .bind() is for? It's *not* to indicate which key you care about.

Comment: :-) I love people that make others think... I've always preferred switch statements in this scenario.

Comment: debugging is nicer when you use console.log if you are going to use alert then go all out and add a blink tag

Comment: Question answered. Feel free to post comments in the reply of my answer :-) @hoandv

Answer (score 2):

#### Here's your **best bet** if you want an **immediate reaction**:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/sZmST/18/

```
$(document).keypress(function(k) {
    switch(k.keyCode){
        // user presses the "F1"
        case 112: alert("F1"); 
        break;
        // user presses the "F2"
        case 113: alert("F2"); 
        break;
    }
});
```

For demonstration for the JS-Fiddle, I provided a working demo of mapping out `keyCode`s:

#### HTML:

```
<input id="whichkey" value="play_here"><span>This will tell you char_code</span>
<p>Click into our body and press F1 or F2. Problem solved.
```

#### Javascript(full):

```
$("#whichkey").on("keydown", function(e) {
    alert(e.which);
});

$(document).keypress(function(k) {
    console.log(k.keyCode);
    switch(k.keyCode)
    {
        // user presses the "F1"
        case 112: alert("F1"); 
        break;

        // user presses the "F2"
        case 113: alert("F2"); 
        break;
    }
});
```

**Yet again, view here. It'll make more sense:**

#### http://jsfiddle.net/sZmST/18/

---

I have the feeling you're trying to expand this, so I'm giving you a solution that you can do so with. I've used this in many javascript games as a `core function`, and it's best to always consider expandability.

Anybody can **golf code** (make it as quick and shortest running as possible), but unless it has a 100% specific task, you'll develop better considering a broader spectrum for what your `function` can do.

Comment: You could always check the green checkbox next to the voting arrows if this helped...

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use `.keyup()` like

```
// f1 = 112
// f2 = 113
// f3 = 114
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 112) {
        console.log("you pressed F1");
    };
}); //keyup
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T29wy/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).keydown( function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 112) alert('f1');
        else if (e.keyCode == 113) alert('f2');
    });
 });
```

JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/C97h6/1

Answer (score 0):

try this code on `dom ready`

```
$('body').keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode=="112")
    {
        alert("f1"); 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if(e.keyCode=="113")
    {
        alert("f2");
       e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9FcWv/1/) here